# Run multiple tools as single bash script

Tags: c++, r, bash, terminal

I am doing different programs in isolation. Let say one command line arg for C++ tool, other one for R. But at first I run command line argument for C++ app, this will gives me a resulting file. Only then I can run another command line for R app, that required resulting file from C++ app.

I may have many different data to be processed. Is there any way to make a bash script to allow looping different tools (C++, R, any other)? So I just sit down and dont manually write many command line arguments?

I would like to go to sleep, while a time consuming loop is making noise in my computer.

Comment: Sure, running multiple commands without user interaction is the fundamental idea of a script.  It's where the term comes from.  What's stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

Running multiple, different programms in some defined order is the fundamental idea of a (systems) scripting language like bash:

```
## run those three programms in sequence
first argument
second parameter
third
# same as
first argument; second parameter; third
```

You can do a lot of fancy things, like redirecting input and output streams:

```
grep secret secrets.file | grep -V strong | sort > result.file
# pipe | feeds everything from the standard output
# of the programm on the left into
# the standard input of the one on the right
```

This includes also things like conditionals and of course, loops:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  preprocess "$file"
  some_work | generate "$file.output"
done < <(find ./data -type f -name 'source*' -print0)
```

As you might see, bash is a programming language on its own, with a bit of a weird syntax IMHO.

Comment: That a good e.g. I am bad at bash. Could you say how to run R script in terminal without firstly going into R interpreter. Like `R myscript.R` ? It just went into R interpret and my other C++ tool can not be run if terminal is switched from normal unix terminal to R interpreter.

Comment: That depends on the interpreter, does it have some kind of batch mode?

Comment: This seems like a good start: https://akastrin.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/batch-processing-with-r/

Comment: Thanks. Works. However, I have complex loop over three different programs (also loop inside one single program for different arguments).. Loop over loop.. Am gonna read the tutorial and get back if it does not work.